# How to get meld to ignore data type differences?

Tags: regex, meld, filemerge

I'm using meld to merge a large file.  The compiler for the source platform uses slightly different data type definitions, and it'd help if there were a way to make meld ignore the data type differences.  For example, it'd be nice if it would ignore differences between `uint8` and `uint8_t`. Is there a way to do that with the Text Filters?

Comment: I don't know, but if you can't find a direct solution you could create modified copies of the files you want to compare, with all occurrences of `uint8` replaced by `uint8_t`. (BTW, if you're using a reasonably modern C or C++ implementation, `uint8_t` is standard and `uint8` is not; you might consider using `uint8_t` everywhere.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks for the suggestion.  I agree.  The old code is what has the `uint8`.  Everything is being updated to use the standard C types (`uint8_t`) as it's ported to the new platform.